# How do I calculate the sum of sum of triangular numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, triangular-numbers

As we know, triangular numbers are a sequence defined by $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. And it's first few terms are $1,3,6,10,15...$. Now I want to calculate the sum of the sum of triangular numbers. Let's define
$$a_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$b_n=\sum_{x=1}^na_x$$
$$c_n=\sum_{x=1}^nb_x$$
And I want an explicit formula for $c_n$. After some research, I found the explicit formula for $b_n=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$. Seeing the patterns from $a_n$ and $b_n$, I figured the explicit formula for $c_n$ would be $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{24}$ or $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{12}$.

Then I tried to plug in those two potential equations,

If $n=1$, $c_n=1$, $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{24}=1$, $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{12}=2$. Thus we can know for sure that the second equation is wrong.

If $n=2$, $c_n=1+4=5$, $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{24}=5$. Seems correct so far.

If $n=3$, $c_n=1+4+10=15$, $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{24}=\frac{360}{24}=15$.

Overall, from the terms that I tried, the formula above seems to have worked. However, I cannot prove, or explain, why that is. Can someone prove (or disprove) my result above?

Comment: They're diagonals in [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Diagonals).

Comment: @JMoravitz I think that's way off. I am dealing with triangular numbers not square numbers here. Also my question is actually a double sum not a single one.

Comment: @JMoravitz There is a more direct answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie I saw this post before. That's how I got $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$. However, I want the sum of *this* sequence.

Comment: In general, $\prod\limits_{k=0}^{p-1} (n+k) = 
\frac{(n+p) - (n-1)}{p+1}\prod\limits_{k=0}^{p-1} (n+k) 
= \frac{1}{p+1}\left(\prod\limits_{k=0}^p(n+k) - \prod\limits_{k=0}^p(n-1 + k)\right)$. Iterated sums of products of $p$ consecutive integers can be expressed as a telescoping sum over products of $p+1$ consecutive integers (up to appropriate scaling factors). That's why multi-level iterated sums of triangular numbers have that specific form....

Comment: Regarding your approach of guessing the formula, and the question of whether the denominator would be 12 or 24, you might note that the denominators in this sequence of formulas are $2=2!$, $6=3!$, and $24=4!$

Comment: "*Dealing with triangular numbers, not square numbers*"  The sum of triangular numbers can be seen as the sum of square numbers plus the sum of natural numbers... the link I provided is perfectly relevant and also includes information on how to generalize to sums of cubes and higher.

Comment: Related: [Finding a closed form for a recursively defined sequence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3948029/215900) Your iterated definitions for $a_n,b_n,c_n$ are given by $a_n=T(3,n-1),~b_n=T(4,n-1)~,c_n=T(5,n-1),\ldots$ where $T(n,k)$ is the recursively defined function in the linked post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to prove your conjecture is by induction. You already checked the case $n=1$, so I won’t do it again. Let’s assume your result is true for some $n$. Then:
$$c_{n+1}=c_n+b_{n+1}$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{24} + \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{6}$$
$$=\frac{n^4+10n^3+35n^2+50n+24}{24}$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}{24}$$
and your result holds for $n+1$.

Answer (score 3):

This can be generalized, in fact if $U_p(n)=(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+p)$ then we have the summation formula (proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4117390/399263))

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n U_p(k)=\frac{1}{p+2}\,U_{p+1}(n)$$

In particular, it is a bit of a pity to see answers in which $\sum i$, $\sum i^2$ and $\sum i^3$ are separated, because this is kind of going against the natural way of solving it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^2=\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^3=\frac {(n(n+1))^2}{4}$$
Use of these $3$ formulae is sufficient to prove the required result.

The derivation of the $3^{rd}$ formula can comes by noting:
$$(r+1)^4-r^4=4r^3+6r^2+4r+1$$
Now sum this identity over $r=1$ to $r=n$, and since $\sum r^2$ and $\sum r$ are already known, the $3^{rd}$ formula gets proven.
In general, using this process, $\sum r^n$ can be derived if $\sum r^{n-1}$ is known.

Comment: Wait so is $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^3=\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}r\right)^2$$

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is a very interesting formula, which has an excellent geometric proof on Wikipedia too.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that after $k$ summations, the formula is

$$\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}.$$

As we can check, by the Pascal identity

$$\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}-\binom{n-1+k-1}{n-2}=\binom{n-1+k-1}{n-1},$$

which shows that the last term of a sum (sum up to $n$ minus sum up to $n-1$) is the sum of the previous stage ($k-1$) up to $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using induction to prove or disprove your attempts?
It tends to be relevant with these equations.

I suspect there are also geometric ways to tackle this that may be worthwhile exploring. Roger Fenn's Geometry has some problems of this nature.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to calculate $5$ terms of $c_n$, recognize that it's going to be a degree-4 formula, and then solve for the coefficients. Thus:

$$c_1 = T_1=1 \\ c_2 = c_1 + (T_1+T_2) = 5 \\ c_3 = c_2+(T_1+T_2+T_3) = 15 \\ c_4 = c_3 + (T_1+T_2+T_3+T_4) = 35 \\ c_5 = c_4 + (T_1+T_2+T_3+T_4+T_5) = 70$$ Now we can find coefficients $A,B,C,D,E$ so that $An^4+Bn^3+Cn^2+Dn+E$ gives us those results when $n=1,2,3,4,5$. This leads to a linear system in 5 unknowns, which we can solve and obtain $A=\frac1{24},B=\frac14,C=\frac{11}{24},D=\frac14,E=0$. Thus taking a common denominator, we have $$c_n=\frac{n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n}{24}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{24}$$
So that agrees with your result.

---

Another way is to use the famous formulas for sums of powers. Thus, we find $b_n$ first: $$b_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i(i+1)}{2} = \frac12\left(\sum i^2 + \sum i\right) = \frac12\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)\\ =\frac{n^3+3n^2+2n}{6}$$

Now, we find $c_n$: $$c_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i^3+3i^2+2i}{6}=\frac16\sum i^3 + \frac12\sum i^2 + \frac13\sum i \\ = \frac16\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} + \frac12\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + \frac13\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\ = \frac{n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n}{24}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{24}$$

So we have confirmed the answer 2 different ways. As is clear from the other solutions given here, there are other ways as well.